# Making Column data Unique in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, key, ssms

Let's say I have a database with several columns.
There is a primary key, Users.
But there is also annother column, Username.
When a new Username is entered into the database, I want to check to make sure it is unique.  Since there is already a primary key, maybe I need to put a constraint on Username.

I have no idea how to do this.  When I right click on the column name and I bring up "Indexes/Keys" I see "Users_Key" for the existing primary key, not "Users".  So I have to add something like "Username_Keys"?  When I do, I don't see it anywhere in the Object Explorer.  But I do see Users_Key under "Keys"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Is it okay to use a query within SSMS?

Cos then you could do this:

```
ALTER TABLE tablename
ADD UNIQUE (Username)
```

where the table is called `tablename` and the Username column (which you want to be unique) is called `Username`.

For multiple columns, do it like this:

```
ALTER TABLE tablename
ADD CONSTRAINT uc_NameofConstraint UNIQUE (column1,column2)
```

To be honest, it's better to do it the second way, as you may need to drop the constraint later for some reason. Like this:

```
ALTER TABLE tablename
DROP CONSTRAINT uc_NameofConstraint
```

Don't forget that a `UNIQUE` constraint has a size limit (I believe it's around 900 bytes, but not 100% sure), so make sure UserName is not a column type like `NVARCHAR(MAX)` or it won't let you do it! But you'd be insane to let anybody have a username over 100 characters anyway!

Comment: Definitly the second way. Nice job there Dommer, this helped me a lot!